# Does the Skype for Business App SDK support direct communication between two users?

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Can I use the [Skype for Business App SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/skypeappsdk) to develop an app that enables two end users to communicate directly with each other via instant messaging, voice or video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this isn't currently possible.  The precise answer depends on whether your end users have Skype for Business accounts:

- The current SDK only supports users that are "guests": i.e. *not* signed in as Skype for Business users.   It is not designed to allow two guests to talk to each other.  Instead, it enables the guest to join a meeting with a licensed Skype for Business user who is attending the meeting via the official Skype for Business application installed on their desktop or mobile device.  Example: a patient using your healthcare app joins a video meeting with their doctor who is using the Skype for Business app.  For more details on this scenario, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/embedskypeb2ccomms .
- In future, the SDK may support users that *are* signed in as Skype for Business users.  This would enable these two licensed users to talk directly to each other from within your app.

Comment: From my custom Android chat client, using SFB Android SDK, I want to allow signed in user in my app to chat with the user who is using SFB Official Android app. Is it possible as of now?